# phonegap cound not get camera pictures in folder tmp

Tags: ios, file, cordova, camera

I encountered a weird problem, I use phonegap camera api for taking picture, the picture is taken, and stored under /tmp, the file is there, but when I try to getFile using File api from imageURI returned by Camera api, I just could not retrieve the file, always return error, can anyone help me (on device)

I always get encoding err when try to get the file, the image is encoded in jpeg

Comment: Might help if you post some code and the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. may this work on IOS & Android not tested.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("your imageURI",sucess,fail);
}

function sucess(fileEntry){
    // you can do with your fileEntry object
}
```